# What purpose do access specifiers for nested class serve?

Tags: c++, access-specifier

Suppose I have a class A with a private nested class B. As I understand it, that means B is not part of the public API. Does that mean that the public and private access specifiers only server the programmer rather than the user? Are there ways that I might accidentally give the user access to public data members of a private nested class?

Comment: API is an Application Programming Interface, so it's intended to be a tool of programmers. No security aspects are involved whatsoever. Moreover as soon as your executable/library is given to a user, any data from it can be extracted / decompiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a private nested class does not mean that you can't accidentally make it available to the "user":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {

private:
  class B {
  public:
    int x = 2;
  };

public:
  B getB() { return B(); }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  
  // a returns B so you have access to the public member x
  auto b1 = a.getB();
  std::cout << b1.x << std::endl;
    
  // or get the return type to create an instance of B  
  using B = std::result_of_t<decltype(&A::getB)(A)>;
  B b2;
  std::cout << b2.x << std::endl;
}
```

So if you have a function in `A`  that is `public`, and exposes `B` (or any other function that is able to expose `B` and to which the "user" as access to) then the user will be able to refer to that nested class even if it is `private`.

`protected` and `private` prevent you from refering to the names directly, but if you purposely (or accidentally) expose them in a different way, then this access modifier won't protect you from that.

Comment: Notice `auto b1` works, but `A::B b1` won't, (as name is private).